# Android:isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) doesn't work.Only isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)

Tags: android, gps, location

When i run my app on my mobile phone i can see that only the GPS_PROVIDER is working properly.The NETWORK_PROVIDER triggers only if GPS_PROVIDER is triggered.
Here is the code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (!lm.isProviderEnabled(locationProvider)) {
        networkCheck();
    }

    // Get Location Manager and check for GPS & Network location services
    if (!lm.isProviderEnabled(gpsProvider)) {
        gpsCheck();

    }


 private void networkCheck() {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NETWORK!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_internet_access_alert_dialog, null);
    Button positiveBtn = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.positiveNetworkBtn);
    final Button negativeBtn = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.negativeNetworkBtn);
    builder.setView(mView);
    final AlertDialog networkDialog = builder.create();
    positiveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            networkDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

    negativeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    networkDialog.setCancelable(false);
    networkDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    networkDialog.show();
}

public void gpsCheck(){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_gps_alert_dialog, null);
    Button positiveBtn = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.positiveBtn);
    final Button negativeBtn = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.negativeBtn);
    builder.setView(mView);
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    positiveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Show location settings when the user acknowledges the alert dialog
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

    negativeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.show();


}
```

I noticed that if location(GPS_ENABLED) is enabled on my phone and the network data are enabled also,the NETWORK_PROVIDER doesn't pop up(Which is correct) but if my location is enabled and the network data are disabled the NETWORK_PROVIDER doesn't pop up also...Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are type of location provider

**NETWORK_PROVIDER**
Name of the network location provider.

**GPS_PROVIDER**
Name of the GPS location provider.

I think you are considering NETWORK_PROVIDER as mobile data, No ? 
Disabling mobile data doesn't mean that you are disabling LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER

On the basis of your input here is the code to test whether **only mobile data** is turned ON/OFF or any of network **either WIFI or mobile data** turned ON/OFF.

```
public class ConnectivityUtils {

    // Returns TRUE any network mobile data or WIFI turned on otherwise returns FALSE
    public static boolean isNetworkConnected(@NonNull Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }

    // Returns TRUE only if mobile data is turned on otherwise returns FALSE
    public static boolean isMobileDataConnected(@NonNull Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mobile = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        return mobile != null && mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just want when the mobile data are disabled to give me an alertdialog.Is there any way to do that instead of checking ifNETWORK_PROVIDER is disabled or not?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your question, accordingly have edited my previous answer with the code example, please look at that and update the answer as accepted if that works for you.

Comment: Ok i will try the code you provided!One more thing...How should i call this class?I mean what parameters should i put inside the ()?Sorry i'm newbie :D

Comment: Just need to pass the application context, in your case call this method from activity like `if (!ConnectivityUtils.isNetworkConnected(this)) {// show your dialog}`

Comment: Now activity onCreate method should be like this `@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (!ConnectivityUtils.isNetworkConnected(this)) {
            // Show your own dialog here
            Toast.makeText(this, "You are not connected,Connect to wifi or mobile data and try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }` Do let me know if works for you, and don't forget to accept the answer